# How to write in one more condition inside input validation?

Tags: javascript

New to Javascript. My function is muddled and I would like some guidance on how to execute this properly.

This function shall display a message (from the `msg[]`) contingent on the status of an input field. Currently, there is only one condition for an input to be considered erroneous - if the input field is empty. I would like to add another condition (if an input is NaN, display appropriate message from another array called `msg2[]`) but I am lost on how to write it in. I know I could just simply utilize `HTML5`'s 'required' attribute or input `type="number"` however, I would like to hard code this function for my personal gain.

How can I make the function choose between 2 conditions and display appropriate message from corresponding array?

```
function validateForm(someForm) {
    document.getElementById('errorMsg').innerHTML = ""; 
    var allInputs = document.getElementById("studentform").getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++) {
        if (allInputs[i].name != "final-average-result" && allInputs[i].name != "final-letter-grade-result") {
            if (allInputs[i].value == "") {


                document.getElementById('errorMsg').innerHTML = msg[i];
                if (currentField) {
                    currentField.style.border = "2px solid #CCC";
                }
                allInputs[i].style.border = "2px dotted #F00";
                currentField = allInputs[i];
                allInputs[i].onclick = function () {
                    this.style.border = "2px dashed #CCC";
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    } // end for
} // end validateForm

var msg = ["Name should not be empty", "This field should not be empty",
"This 3rd field should not be empty", "The last field should not be empty."];
var msg2 = ["Invalid input", "error message here",......."]
```

Comment: Please use array of objects for your error  messages instead of creating new arrays for different messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Us if else and `isNaN() function`

```
function validateForm(someForm) {
  document.getElementById('errorMsg').innerHTML = ""; 
   var allInputs = 
  document.getElementById("studentform").getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++) {
    if (allInputs[i].name != "final-average-result" && allInputs[i].name != "final- 
       letter-grade-result") {
        if (allInputs[i].value == "") {

          document.getElementById('errorMsg').innerHTML = msg[i];
            if (currentField) {
              currentField.style.border = "2px solid #CCC";
            }
            allInputs[i].style.border = "2px dotted #F00";
            currentField = allInputs[i];
            allInputs[i].onclick = function () {
              this.style.border = "2px dashed #CCC";
            }
            return;
        } else if(isNaN(allInputs[i].value)) {
            // display error
        }
      }
    } // end for
} // end validateForm

var msg = ["Name should not be empty", "This field should not be empty",
"This 3rd field should not be empty", "The last field should not be empty."];
var msg2 = ["Invalid input", "error message here",......."]
```

Comment: But there is a problem with the whole approach of using arrays for different type of errors, In this particular case, msg2 will be only good for checking NaN errors on the fields that should be numbers, and he will have to go on adding arrays for each type of value he wants to validate.

Comment: I will suggest he use array of objects

Answer (score 0):

You can use an else if statement like

```
if (input != condition ){}
else if (input != condition ){}
```

The statement `if (allInputs[i].name != "final-average-result" && allInputs[i].name != "final-letter-grade-result")` is also incorrect. You should use || operator instead of &&. `allInputs[i].name` will not be equal to 2 strings at same time

Comment: Thank you for responding, but sadly, your suggestion did not work.

Comment: The statement is correct. He uses `!=`, so he checks if its not equal

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different possibilites to consider when performing input validation. There are plugins, and frameworks etc that help you, where you have gone down a fairly manual brick and mortar approach. But thats beside the point...

I find that there are problems with your logic, and there is where you should start to refactor your solution. You are using an array implicitly to hold the error messages for all imput fields. So that first input has a custom error message in the first slot in msg array. This seems to be extremely brittle and will break at some point, you already have a filter which removes two fields from this order, are you sure you compensate for that? Also, you seem to stop at first invalid field?

When trying to validate type of value for msg2, and if you want to support differnet kind of values and validations, this logic won't work. You need to be able to use different requirements for different fields, and perhaps several validation criterias for one field...

You simply need to work out another strategy. One close to your attempt would be to structure your fields in a object by field name or id, and then have a corresponding object for validation, where fields represent validation error for a specific type of error.

```
var inputFieldValidationErrorMap = {
    'first-field-name': {
        empty: 'Name should not be empty',
        wordchars: 'Name must be only valid letter chars'
    },
    'second-field-name': {
        empty: 'This field should not be empty',
        nan: 'This field must contain only numbers'
    }
}
```

To use this in your current code, you'd write something like

```
function validateForm(someForm) {
    document.getElementById('errorMsg').innerHTML = ""; 
    var allInputs = document.getElementById("studentform").getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++) {
        if (allInputs[i].name != "final-average-result" && allInputs[i].name != "final-letter-grade-result") {
            var name = allInputs[i].name;
            var errorElement = document.getElementById('errorMsg');
            var validation = inputFieldValidationErrorMap[name];
            if (allInputs[i].value === "" && 'empty' in validation) {
                errorElement.innerHTML = validation.empty;
                return;
            } else if(isNaN(allInputs[i].value) && 'nan' in validation) {
                errorElement.innerHTML = validation.nan;
                return;
            }
        //... Go on here for every type of validation you support
        }
    } // end for
} // end validateForm
```

**Further improvements**

This solution is by no means perfect, and it has its limitations as well. You could also use some data attribute on your input fields to contain your validation requirements, and you should combine your solution with setting correct input types etc, using native html attirbutes for better usability. You should allow each input to display its own error, and run validation passes through all fields in the form so that all errors are current. There are frameworks and plugins to consider as well, to be sure your not running into trouble.